# How to dismiss flutter dialog?

Tags: dialog, flutter

I am new to flutter, I want to dismiss my dialog after the task completion. I've tried with:

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

But my screen is getting black and dialog is still up there. here is my dialog code.

```
Dialog _dialog = new Dialog(
  child: new Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAsixSize.min, 
    children: <Widget> [
    new CircularProgressIndicator(), 
    new Text("Loading")]),     

);
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html says

> The dialog route created by this method is pushed to the root navigator. If the application has multiple Navigator objects, it may be necessary to call `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(result)` to close the dialog rather just `Navigator.pop(context, result)`.

so I'd assume one of these two should do what you want.

Comment: what is 'result' here?

Comment: `result` is an optional argument that the `route` which called `showDialog` can receive. It's useful if for example your dialog select a value that the UI need to use.

Comment: Any value you want the `Future` returned from `showDialog()` complete with when you dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, its working for real device but same is still there on Simulator.

Comment: Hard to tell if it works on the device. A wild guess would be `flutter clean`. What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: 0.3.2 sounds a bit outdated. What is actually the current state. " its working for real device" and "also not working for android device" seem contradicting.

Comment: working for iOS device, but not for android device and simulator, let me try to upgrade flutter. and Thanks a lot @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have a login page as `initialRoute`, I need to call `Navigator.pop(context)` when login succeeds, and I also need to show a dialog during login, that means **I need to call `Navigator.pop(context)` twice**, otherwise, just dialog is dismissed, the login page is still there. It's kind of confused to have two `pop`, why not dialog.dismiss()? Thanks

Comment: you saved me from a minor headache

Comment: I cannot edit the link. The right one is [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

Answer (score 89):

This code works for me:

```
  BuildContext dialogContext;
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      dialogContext = context;
      return Dialog(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            new Text("Loading"),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );

  await _longOperation();
  Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Using the context that's not from the builder causes the screen to navigate pop instead of closing the dialog.

Comment: Agreed to @AxesGrinds

Comment: What happens here if the user press back button while the _longOperation is still in progress?

Comment: Awesome, this helped me with an edge case where the dialog won't dismiss using a basic `Navigator.of(context).pop()`. Thanks!

Comment: how to return something with this? Navigator.pop(dialogContext,variable)?

Comment: Agree with 'Axes Grinds'. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me with a popup inside a CupertinoTabScaffold. The screen below would be dismissed, but the popup would stay (and clicking again throws an exception that the widget has no root). A CupertinoTabScaffold has multiple navigator objects, while the dialog is pushed to the root navigator.

Answer (score 35):

If you don't want to return any result after `showDialog` is closed, you can use

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

If you want to pass result call

```
Navigator.pop(context, result);
```

---

Example:

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Wanna Exit?'),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false), // passing false
            child: Text('No'),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true), // passing true
            child: Text('Yes'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }).then((exit) {
  if (exit == null) return;

  if (exit) {
    // user pressed Yes button
  } else {
    // user pressed No button
  }
});
```

Answer (score 22):

```
//it work conrrectly
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
},
```

Answer (score 14):

Generally `Navigator.pop(context);` works.

But If the application has multiple Navigator objects and dialogBox doesn't close, then try this

`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();`

If you want to pass result call, try

`Navigator.pop(context,result);`

OR

`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(result);`

Answer (score 11):

Better to use Completer, because if your operation is too short or the device is too slow, then the dialogContext variable will not be initialized and you can't close the dialog.

```
final dialogContextCompleter = Completer<BuildContext>();
showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
    if(!dialogContextCompleter.isCompleted) {
      dialogContextCompleter.complete(dialogContext);
    }
    return AlertDialog(
      content: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  },
);

// Close progress dialog
final dialogContext = await dialogContextCompleter.future;
Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. I had to detect whether multiple dialogs were opened and handle situations to only have single dialog opened. This was the only way to reliably close them.

Answer (score 5):

In 2023 here is the latest way to do that. Because in my case `Navigator.of(context).pop();` didn't work

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

This will close the dialog/alert box.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
);

await Future<int>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will definitely work. use the context of pageBuilder in Navigator to pop the dialog from screen.

```
showGeneralDialog(
     context: context,
     barrierLabel: "XYZ",
     barrierDismissible: true,
     barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
     pageBuilder: (dialogContext, __, ___) {
       return Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 240,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          decoration: bd,
          child: SizedBox.expand(
              GestureDetector(
                   onTap: (){
                       Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
                    },
                    child: const Padding(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,0,10,0),
                       child: Icon(Icons.close, size: 26, color:Colors.white),
                     ),
               ),
           )
         ) 
       );
     }
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_dialogContext` to handle closing the dialog, just you should check some conditions before calling pop() `(_dialogContext != null && _dialogContext!.mounted)`.

```
    BuildContext? _dialogContext;    
    
    showDialog<void>(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (ctx) {
                        _dialogContext = ctx;
                        return AlertDialog(content: child);
                      },
                    );
    
    
    //close dialog
     if (_dialogContext != null && _dialogContext!.mounted) {
          Navigator.pop(_dialogContext!);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add on to Günter's answers. If you need to dismiss it when the user clicks elsewhere
change this property to true

```
barrierDismissible: true,
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from @live-long, you can create a class to handle the showing and dismissing of the dialog.

Example:

```
class ProcessingDialog {
  ProcessingDialog({
    required this.context,
    required this.child,
  });
  final BuildContext context;
  final Widget child;
  BuildContext? dialogContext;

  void showProcessingDialog() {
    if (dialogContext != null && dialogContext!.mounted) {
      Navigator.pop(dialogContext!);
    }
    if (!context.mounted) {
      return;
    }
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (ctx) {
        dialogContext = ctx;
        return AlertDialog(content: child);
      },
    );
  }

  void dismissProcessingDialog() {
    if (dialogContext != null && dialogContext!.mounted) {
      Navigator.pop(dialogContext!);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
final processingDialog =
    ProcessingDialog(context: context, child: const Text('Processing...'));
processingDialog.showProcessingDialog();
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
processingDialog.dismissProcessingDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static Future<BuildContext?> wait(BuildContext context, String title) async {
   BuildContext? dialogContext;
   showDialog(
     context: context,
     builder: (BuildContext context) {
       dialogContext = context;
       return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: MyColors.color_primary_dark(),
          surfaceTintColor: MyColors.color_primary_dark(),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          content: StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStatePopupMain) {
            return Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 2, color: MyColors.color_attention()),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              MyText(title, color: MyColors.text_always_white()),
            ]);
          }));
    });
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  return dialogContext;}
```

and use like this:

```
BuildContext? dialogContext= await  wait(context,"Loding...");
// do heveay work
Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
```