# Flutter - Clear a Dialog when you are using the AppBar Back Funciton. How do you clear the Navigator when going back to previous screen

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, loading, dismiss

I am using the following method to call a loading dialog before going to the next screen , but when i return to the previous page with the App Bars back function the Loading indicator is still loading.

How do you clear all Navigators when going back?

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      });
```

Comment: Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/50683571/15215450

Answer (score 1):

Probably you call `Navigator.of(context).pop()`. `Context` is an interesting but also hard to well-understand in Flutter. Well, I could say this: EACH screen has it own context. But when you open modal bottom sheet & dialog, it creates another context. It's kinda confusing if you don't carefully notice (dev usually named every context variables is `context`). Therefore, when you tap on back button on app bar and call `Navigator.of(context).pop()`, it is context **of the screen, not the dialog**. You can follow the link: [How to dismiss flutter dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683524/how-to-dismiss-flutter-dialog/50683571#50683571)