# How to remove or hide a dialog created above a WebView after the requested page finishes loading?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using webview_flutter. I would like to show a CircularProgressIndicator from the moment the user clicks a link until the page loads. To achieve that, I created a method that shows the indicator at the center of the page on top of the WebView. The method is as follows:

```
buildShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
   return showDialog (
     context: context,
     barrierDismissible: false,
     builder: (BuildContext context) {
       return Center (
         child: CircularProgressIndicator (),
       );
     });
  }
```

Then I call it on the onNavigationRequest event of a NavigationDelegate that I setup when I configure the WebView: when I configure the webView like this

```
...
NavigationDelegate(
   onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
     buildShowDialog(context);
     return NavigationDecision.navigate;
   }
   onPageFinished: (string value){
     Navigator.of(context).pop();
   }
...
```

This works and I see the indicator in the center of the page as the page itself loads under it. To remove the indicator, I thought to go to onPageFinished event and pop the dialog out like this:

```
onPageFinished: (String value) {Navigator.of(context).pop();}
```

But I get an error on the physical device (the yellow font on the red background) with '_history.isNotEmpty: is not true.'. I'm trying to pop something that is not there?

On my tests, if I remove the Navigator.of(context).pop(); line from onPageFinished I can manually remove the progress dialog by pressing the back button on the device, so I guess I'm looking for a way to achieve this programmatically.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Many thanks.

Comment: Related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683524/how-to-dismiss-flutter-dialog but using either Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(result) or Navigator.pop(context, result) on the onPageFinished event works for me. I think it's because the dialog is not rendered at the moment onPageFinished is called, does that make sense?